# object method calling with various overriding methods

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

I ran into this code:

```
public class AAA
{
       protected int _num;
       public AAA()
        {
            _num=2;
        }
       public boolean equals(Object other)
       {
           System.out.println("objectA");
           return true;
        }
}
public class BBB extends AAA
{
    String st;
   public BBB()
        {
           st="bbb";
        }
   public boolean equals(Object other)
        {
        System.out.println("objectB");
        return true;
        }
   public boolean AAA(AAA other)
        {
        System.out.println("AAA");
        return true;
        }
   public boolean BBB(BBB other)
        {
        System.out.println("BBB");
        return true;
        }
}
public class Driver15a
{
    public static void main(String args[])
        {   
            AAA ab=new BBB();
            BBB b1=new BBB();
            if(ab.equals(ab)) System.out.println(6);
}
}
```

I expected ab to either:

-use AAA method of equals.

-call the method from BBB with Object signature.

However it calls the method with BBB signature, which is strange to me.

Would appreciate your feedback on how this code runs actually to understand method calling.
Thank you!

Comment: If my answer to your previous question is not clear enough, all you had to do was ask me to elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods `public boolean AAA(AAA)` and `public Boolean BBB(BBB)` have nothing to do with this. If I cut it back to the smallest amount of code needed to show what is happening:

```
public class AAA
{
    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        System.out.println("objectA");
        return true;
    }
}

public class BBB extends AAA
{
    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        System.out.println("objectB");
        return true;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{   
    AAA ab=new BBB();
    ab.equals(ab);
}
```

This is a basic example of polymorphism. `BBB.equals(Object)` overrides `AAA.equals(Object)`, so when you call `ab.equals(ab)`, it finds the most overridden version, `BBB.equals(Object)`.